# ignoring return value of ‘system’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result ---GCC compiler linux

Tags: linux, gcc

```
const char *p;

p="curl -d \'{\"switch\": \"00:00:3a:46:3b:8d:df:40\", \"name\":\"flow\", \"cookie\":\"0\",    
\"priority\":\"32768\", \"src-ip\":\""+p+"\",\"active\":\"true\", \"actions\":\"output=all\"}\' 
http://54.68.77.30:8080/wm/staticflowentrypusher/json";

system(p);
```

error: ignoring return value of ‘system’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Werror=unused-result]
     system(p);

Can someone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Stop ignoring the return value of `system()`.  It's bad for your health.